# In Google Sheets, can I make a named range using data from multiple sheets in the same workbook?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, named-ranges

I want to take the same column in each of several dozen sheets and make all the data in all of those columns part of the same named range.

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, that is not possible. for each sheet, you would need to create a separate named range.

Comment: Do you know of a way to detect duplicate data across multiple sheets in the same Google Sheets workbook? Basically what I need to do is identify and count identical entries across multiple sheets. If the same entry appears on multiple sheets, I want to know.

Comment: @Dave see your previous question for example